# Почему водка — царская?

Tags: этимология

Смесь соляной и азотной кислоты называют царской водкой. Интересно, почему водкой и, главное, почему царской?
Спасибо

Comment: Извините, не в тему, но не могу удержаться: давно мечтаю, чтобы на рынке появился бренд «водка "Царская"». Неужели никто до сих пор не догадался?

Comment: Кстати, да! Бегите патентовать, пока другие не заняли место)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алхимики назвали “царской водкой” за способность растворять золото, считавшееся “царем металлов”. Метафора.